# How can I have one large image over several smaller adjoining divs

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table-like bunch of divs exposed as follow:

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='smaller'>1</div><div class='smaller image'>2</div><div class='smaller image'>3</div><div class='smaller image'>4</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='row'>
    <div  class='smaller'>5</div><div class='smaller image'>6</div><div class='smaller image'>7</div><div class='smaller image'>8</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='row'>
    <div  class='smaller'>9</div><div class='smaller image'>10</div><div class='smaller image'>11</div><div class='smaller image'>12</div>
  </div>      
  
  <div class='row'>
    <div  class='smaller'>13</div><div class='smaller'>14</div><div class='smaller '>15</div><div class='smaller '>16</div>
  </div>            
  
</div>
```

The image layout above was produced by the following css:

```
#container {
  background-color:yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

#container .row .smaller {
  background: white;
  border:  1px solid grey;        
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;      
}

#container .row .smaller.image {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

which can be easily replaced as needed.

I need to place an image over greyed divs (2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12) keeping the whole thing responsive

As read somewhere, I tried the  "`background-attachment: fixed;`" approach which is not working when scrolling down the page

How to achieve this?

Comment: can you show us the css too?

Comment: If we follow your table example, you should be able to do it easily with Javascript (you get up left corner pos of div 2 and down right corner pos of div 12 and then position an image and set size accordingly). However, it may not work if your situation is more complicated than the one you are giving us.

Comment: Is there any need to have those grid items as separate grid items if you are going to place an image over them all? Perhaps a picture of what the final result it to look like plus please include your CSS in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you have a grid, with the right hand upper items as one larger item.

If the image is to cover the items you have shown grayed out then there is no need to have them as separate cells and you can use CSS grid's template-area system to create the grid, with the image set as a background to the second cell.

Here's a simple snippet showing that. Note that the grayed out divs have been removed from the HTML as have the row divs as CSS grid will take care of that:

```css
#container {
  width: min(600px, 100vmin);
  height: min(300px, 50vmin);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "A B B B" "C B B B" "D B B B" "E F G H";
}

#container>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-style: solid;
}

#container :nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: A;
}

#container :nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: B;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

#container :nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: C;
}

#container :nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: D;
}

#container :nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: E;
}

#container :nth-child(6) {
  grid-area: F;
}

#container :nth-child(7) {
  grid-area: G;
}

#container :nth-child(8) {
  grid-area: H;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```

Obviously you will want to alter the sizes/aspect ratio of the container to suit your application.

Comment: So smart! Please do note this solution will only work after removing the `<div class='row'> [divs on the same row] </div>` element. Thanks!

Comment: This approach is very interesting. Still won't work here because we are not allowed to change HTML markup. As you see in question, grey cells they do exist, white in your answer you are merging all those grey cells into one.
Do you maybe have another answer handling all those 16 cells? 
Thanks so far.

Comment: How is the height of each row defined?

Comment: from computed tab:
height 35.1719px 
line-height 24.591px

Comment: Figured out with some js:
1. map cells to be removed into array
`
 let image_cells = [
      // col, row
      [10,0],[11,0],[12,0],[13,0],[14,0],[15,0],[16,0],
      [9,1],[10,1],[11,1],[12,1],[13,1],[14,1],[15,1],[16,1],
       etc
    ];

`
2. remove useless cells
` $(".grid").find('div.square').each(function (i, e) {
      $.each(image_cells, function(index, v) {
        if ( $(element).data("col") == v[0] && $(e).data("row") ==   v[1]  )  {
          $('div.square[data-col="' + $(element).data("col") + '"][data-row="' + $(e).data("row") + '"]').remove();
      }});});`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into another option other than Javascript this can be achieved with CSS Grid layout using Column and Row placements. Quick example, I have only 8 grid items because where the image resides, it takes up all those cells.

**Edit:** reworked for 16 cells and used pseudo element on grid for 17th cell image overlay.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, [col] 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, [row] 100px);
  position: relative;
}
.grid:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  grid-column: col 2 / 5;
  grid-row: row 1 / 4;
  z-index: 2;
}
.grid-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: rgba(14, 67, 92, .5);
}
.item-1 {
  grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
  grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
}
.item-2 {
  grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
  grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
}
.item-3 {
  grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
  grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
}
.item-4 {
  grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
  grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
}
.item-5 {
  grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
  grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
}
.item-6 {
  grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
  grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
}
.item-7 {
  grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
  grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
}
.item-8 {
  grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
  grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
}
.item-9 {
  grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
  grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
}
.item-10 {
  grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
  grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
}
.item-11 {
  grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
  grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
}
.item-12 {
  grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
  grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
}
.item-13 {
  grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
  grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
}
.item-14 {
  grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
  grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
}
.item-15 {
  grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
  grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
}
.item-16 {
  grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
  grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-9">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-10">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-11">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-12">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-13">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-14">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-15">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-16">16</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Example #2

```css
#container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, [col] 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(4, [row] 35px);
      grid-gap: 1px;
      position: relative;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    #container:before {
      content: "";
      background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1000x500");
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center center;
      grid-column: col 2 / 5;
      grid-row: row 1 / 4;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    #container > div {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
      z-index: 0;
      background-color: rgba(69, 129, 123, 1);
    }
    #container div:nth-child(1) {
      grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
      grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(2) {
      grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
      grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(3) {
      grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
      grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(4) {
      grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
      grid-row: row 1 / 2 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(5) {
      grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
      grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(6) {
      grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
      grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(7) {
      grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
      grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(8) {
      grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
      grid-row: row 2 / 3 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(9) {
      grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
      grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(10) {
      grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
      grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(11) {
      grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
      grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(12) {
      grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
      grid-row: row 3 / 4 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(13) {
      grid-column: col 1 / 2 ;
      grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(14) {
      grid-column: col 2 / 3 ;
      grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(15) {
      grid-column: col 3 / 4 ;
      grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
    }
    #container div:nth-child(16) {
      grid-column: col 4 / 5 ;
      grid-row: row 4 / 5 ;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting! This solution requires HTML img tag to be added. Receiving HTML from an external module (we are on Drupal), this may take extra work. Thanks.

Comment: I can modify it to use a background image and use the same numbering and appearance if needed.

Comment: This approach is very interesting. Still won't work here because we are not allowed to change HTML markup. As you see in question, grey cells they do exist, white in your answer you are merging all those grey cells into one.
Do you maybe have another answer handling all those 16 cells? 
Thanks so far.

Comment: Yes, I have modified it to use 16 cells and added a pseudo element to the grid class giving me the 17th cell to overlay the image in the specified col/row grid.

Comment: Added another example.